# Cisco numeric EIGRP routing IP summarizing and routing

Tags: cisco, routing, eigrp, route-summarization

I have 2 routers connected via Serial 0/0/0 both running EIGRP with an ASN of 65000, and i want to advertise and summarize the interfaces, being just my loopbacks, and set the loopbacks as passive. lastly setting the hello timer to 10 and hold to 20.

Are just show R2 commands as they are almost the same, except for the loopback address are different.

the ip address for my loopbacks on R2 are

```
loopback 1: 172.17.1.1 /26
loopback 65: 172.17.1.65 /26
loopback 129: 172.17.1.129 /26
loopback 193: 172.17.1.193 /26
```

Which i calculated to be:

```
172.17.1.1/26       10101100.00010000.00000001.00011010
172.17.1.65/26      10101100.00010000.00000001.01000001
172.17.1.129/26     10101100.00010000.00000001.10000001
172.17.1.193/26     10101100.00010000.00000001.11000001

// first 3 octs match so from /26 to /24 equals 172.17.1.0 255.255.255.0  correct ??
```

And here's my commands for R2

```
# router eigrp 65000
# eigrp router-id 2.2.2.2
# network 172.17.1.0 255.255.255.0
# passive-interface lo 1
# passive-interface lo 65
# passive-interface lo 129
# passive-interface lo 193
# exit
# int s0/0/0
# ip summary-address eigrp 65000 172.17.1.0 255.255.255.0
# ip hello-int eigrp 65000 10
# ip hold-time eigrp 65000 20
```

Is that all correct ? i don't have GNS3 and my packet tracer does not like all the commands, and i can't afford to buy either's full version :(. I shall try 7.1 tonight as i hear that can run basic eigrp.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

The configuration you have shown is correct and will work as long as EIGRP is working over your serial link